# How to use log files in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am learning codeigniter,i want a log file which will help me save all the changes on the web when ever it happens with the content and the time.
Do you know any document that i can learn about this log file with codeigniter?
Please help, i am just a beginner so that please give me a very simple and detail about this file.
Hope that some one can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use official log error:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

You can check the log file in: application\logs\yourlog

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have hooks. They runs before some event (before start framework, befor action, and etc). You can write in file all data you needed.